I don't know if my connections are correct. (Schematic to breadboard)
This is intended to be a voltage multiplier.
Can anyone check if my connections are correct or accurate to my schematic?



What's this circuit supposed to do?

That is VERY hard on the brain (mine anyway :-)). I could draw it out more comventionally BUT I suggest it would be far better if you can draw it with left to right flow and with ground at the bottom. At a glance it looks like you have mixed "live" and ground nodes in various places so that you do not get follow through pumping action. || Imagine a square wave in. Starting at the oscillator raise and lower C2 input and record what happens. Then look at right hand end of C2 and do the same. Co=ntinue down chain. I think your chain does not exist.

|| ALSO add some description at the start or people will quickly close this question.

@Lundin  Voltage multiplier (I hope :-) )

Snow Fairy24 Please check my added desciption, change if wrong AND regardless, add a bit more information.

I honestly don't know what I'm doing even with enough research, my prof don't explain much as well. It's supposed to be a Voltage Quintupler (?) circuit with 2 doublers and a single stage rectifier.

@RussellMcMahon Hi, where can I check this added description?

Why can't you simulate it and check it yourself?

Regarding schematic, the two doublers are certainly ok. But the rectifier will charge the most bottom cap through middle cap. That is not a perfect solution. I would connect the upper side of bottom cap to doublers middle (power supply minus). Regarding tinker, the three diodes parallel are wrong for sure.

Very very first thing: add labels to the components on your breadboard. You'll immediately realise that you're missing at least one component! Then trace each connection between components, and you'll realise that there are quite a few issues.

The "black input line" (Labeled "-" on your breadboard) should connect directly to four components, but I only count three.
Trick is this: while a solderless breadboard cannot be connected in arbitrary ways, you can always rearrange your schematic such that it reflects the connections on the breadboard. So, use the schematic capture software used to produce your schematic, and rearrange that, without removing connections or adding new ones between components that were formerly connected, until you get something you can plug into a circuit board, directly.
In more technical terms, while a schematic and your fritzing breadboard drawing are both representations of a circuit, the circuit functionality is defined by its connectivity graph, i.e., a list of which pins are connected to each other, and which components have which pin. You can rotate your schematic, you can stretch or shorten lines and do many things to your schematic, whithout affecting that graph. Only if your schematic and the breadboard have the same graph can the breadboard show the same circuit as your schematic.
So. First step, label the components in your breadboard image. That solves 90% of confusion. Then, for every pin in your schematic, find it in your breadboard, and make sure it's connected to exactly the same pins as in your schematic. Mark all the connections you've checked in green in your schematic, directly after checking. Mark all the components you've checked in green. When your whole schematic is green, you've verified that you've built an equivalent breadboard.

This is the circuit you have created on breadboard:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Which probably could be drawn better but it gives me a 404 error when I try to edit it (posted too quickly) and it's not worth doing again as the breadboard has no designators so I have no idea what is supposed to be what.
However, you can see clearly that your breadboard circuit is not what is in your schematic


Figure 1. First error.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 2. What you have made.
There are no component designators on your breadboard layout so I don't know which component is which but it is clear that you have connected three diodes in a parallel / anti-parallel arrangement which doesn't exist in your schematic.

I suggest you rip-up and retry, a common term coined in the early days of PCB layout tools.

Daisy-chain all the diodes in a string horizontally. You can stand them up "Manhatten style" as the Japanese started in miniature radios or like this /////.
Orient all the polarized Caps the same way using the BLUE rail to GND and RED rail to SIG GEN.
Note I have used 3 stages but show the repeatability of 2 diodes and 2 caps.
I have also included an interactive load switch and plotted power & voltage.

My Simulation link

